# Rails already has getters and setters without me setting an attr_accessor. How do I stop all setters ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attr-accessor

Here is my class, as you can see, no attr_accessor

```
class LegacyBlogPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection Rails.configuration.database_configuration['blogs']
  self.table_name = 'blogpost'
  self.primary_key = 'post_id'
end
```

But I can still read and write all variables. Is this default behavior ?

```
x = LegacyBlogPost.find(172925)
x.title += "."
x.save
=> true
```

My main question though, is how do I avoid ever writing to this class ? 
I understand I could make the mysql user only be allowed to do select statements. Also I belive I could re-write the rails setters to just return as soon as the method is hit. But I had assumed if I just set attr_reader's for everything, the writers just wouldn't be there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ActiveRecord` automatically creates getters\setters to read\write for all columns

If you want to make the model a read only do

```
class LegacyBlogPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  def readonly?
    return true
  end
end
```

To prevent it from being destroyed you can use

```
def before_destroy
  raise ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord
end
```

credit http://blog.zobie.com/2009/01/read-only-models-in-activerecord/

Comment: Nice. Just to clarify I just tested it without the before_destroy and it worked fine, so its only the readonly? method that really matters for stopping setters.

Answer (score -1):

Look into using [`attr_accessible`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html).